# Extra pieces in my set - Eiffel Tower

Tags: building

I recently purchased a Eiffel Tower Architecture kit and I found it having 9 extra pieces.  I know it is normal to have extras but I think the amount is a bit high.  Any ideas or explanations?

Does anyone else have high numbers like this in their architecture sets?

Comment: Most of the times it's not really a matter of number of extra pieces but what they are. If a set uses 9 different colors of 1x1 round plates, for example, you'll get an extra for each color no matter what? So, what are the extras?

Answer (score 5):

According to [the BrickLink inventory](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=21019-1), there should be three extra parts, so 9 seems a bit high.

It could be a mistake from LEGO, but honestly it's more likely that you forgot them yourself. Knowing what the 6 parts are through Bricklink, I suggest you check the model once more to verify where they could go.